# Finding the smaller number of two given the ratio between sum, difference and product

Tags: problem-solving, ratio

How would you find the smaller of two numbers given the ratio between their sum, difference and product? I've been struggling with this one for a while. 
For example: the ratio between the sum, difference and product is 6:4:15 and the numbers are positive integers

Comment: Perhaps a good way to start is some algebra. If a and b are your numbers, you can write

Comment: Perhaps you can start by setting up equations that express these "ratios" for the sum, difference, and product. e..g. $$ (a+b)x = 6 $$ $$ (a-b)x = 4 $$ $$ abx = 15 $$ Then solve for any positive integers $a,b$ since you have three equations in three unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the sum and difference, if the unknown numbers are $a,b$, then there is some real $k$ such that $$a+b=6k$$
and $$a-b=4k$$
We can then solve this to get $a=5k, b=k$.  Now, the product is $5k^2$, and using the ratio relationship, $$5k^2=15k$$
from which we conclude $k=3$ and hence $a=15, b=3$.  A second, less interesting, solution, is $k=0$, which gives $a=b=0$.